# Android media viewer SDK (equivalent of iOS QLPreviewController)

Tags: android, sdk, media, display, qlpreviewcontroller

As far as I understand there is still no equivalent component to iOS's QLPreviewController in Android. I'm looking for an easy way to be able to integrate display of media files (images, movies, PDFs, audio) into my app without using Intents. Are there any known 3rd party SDKs for this task?

Comment: you got any solution.please share me

Comment: @saravananI'm still using https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-pdfview for PDF and regular intents for pictures and movies.

Answer (score 0):

we show in the web view with help of gview this below code

```
 webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        String url = "http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&toolbar=hide&url=" + link;
        webView.loadUrl(url);
```